# Getting "value must be an integer" when trying to seed YAML data

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, yaml, unique

I'm using Django 2, Python 3.7 and the django-address module (https://pypi.org/project/django-address/).  I'm trying to insert some seed data.  I have this YAML ...

```
- model: address.locality
  pk: 1
  fields:
    name: "Chicago"
    postal_code: "60053"
    state:
      name: IL
      country:
      - United States
```

When I run my seed command

```
python manage.py loaddata maps/fixtures/seed_data.yaml
```

I get this error ...

```
localhost:web davea$ python manage.py loaddata maps/fixtures/seed_data.yaml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 923, in to_python
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'dict'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/python.py", line 157, in Deserializer
    data[field.attname] = model._meta.get_field(field_name).to_python(field_value)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 928, in to_python
    params={'value': value},
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'{'name': 'IL', 'country': ['United States']}' value must be an integer."]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 72, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 113, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 168, in load_label
    for obj in objects:
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/pyyaml.py", line 73, in Deserializer
    yield from PythonDeserializer(yaml.load(stream, Loader=SafeLoader), **options)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/python.py", line 159, in Deserializer
    raise base.DeserializationError.WithData(e, d['model'], d.get('pk'), field_value)
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/maps/fixtures/seed_data.yaml': ["'{'name': 'IL', 'country': ['United States']}' value must be an integer."]: (address.locality:pk=1) field_value was '{'name': 'IL', 'country': ['United States']}'
```

I have added this in the file maps/monkey_patching.py to help with auto-creating the entities based on unique identifiers ...

```
from address import State
from address import Country

def country_get_by_natural_key(self, name):
    return self.get_or_create(name=name)[0]

def state_get_by_natural_key(self, name, country_id):
    return self.get_or_create(name=name, country_id=country_id)[0]

Country.add_to_class("get_by_natural_key",country_get_by_natural_key)
State.add_to_class("get_by_natural_key",state_get_by_natural_key)
```

**Edit:** including stack trace per Shivam's request ...

```
(venv) localhost:maps davea$ python web/manage.py loaddata web/maps/fixtures/seed_data.yaml 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 923, in to_python
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/python.py", line 157, in Deserializer
    data[field.attname] = model._meta.get_field(field_name).to_python(field_value)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 928, in to_python
    params={'value': value},
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'['IL', 'United States']' value must be an integer."]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "web/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "web/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 72, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 113, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 168, in load_label
    for obj in objects:
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/pyyaml.py", line 73, in Deserializer
    yield from PythonDeserializer(yaml.load(stream, Loader=SafeLoader), **options)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/python.py", line 159, in Deserializer
    raise base.DeserializationError.WithData(e, d['model'], d.get('pk'), field_value)
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/maps/fixtures/seed_data.yaml': ["'['IL', 'United States']' value must be an integer."]: (address.locality:pk=1) field_value was '['IL', 'United States']'
```

Comment: Did you consider the case that the `state` field is related to `State` model by a foreignkey ? In this case you should add an `integer pk` for this relation rather than the string which should represented in the `State` model.

Comment: I would like the primary keys to be defined automatically which is why I defined the function "state_get_by_natural_key".  Of course, maybe I'm not defining that correctly and that's why I'm having these issues in teh first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue with natural key

`get_by_natural_key` method is available on the manager level but you are adding method on model level. So instead of above, you need to do like this:

```
from django.db import models
from address.models import State

class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, name):
        return self.get_or_create(name=name)[0]

State.add_to_class('objects', CustomManager())
```

## Issue with fixtures

Nested data of fixtures should only contain args and not kwargs. Check [Is there a way in a seed_data.yaml file to autogenerate models on which first model is dependent upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59940160/is-there-a-way-in-a-seed-data-yaml-file-to-autogenerate-models-on-which-first-mo/60029376#60029376) for more detail. And after that, you need to design your `get_by_natural_key` function accordingly. So for `locality` model fixtures would look like

```
- model: address.locality
  pk: 1
  fields:
    name: "Chicago"
    postal_code: "60053"
    state: ['I', 'United States']
```

And overrided manager would be

```
class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, state_name, country):
        country = Country.objects.get_or_create(name=country)[0]
        return State.objects.get_or_create(name=state_name, country=country)[0]

setattr(State._meta, 'default_manager', CustomManager())
```

Comment: Gave this a go, but it results in an "raise base.DeserializationError.WithData(e, d['model'], d.get('pk'), field_value)
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/maps/fixtures/seed_data.yaml': ["'['IL', 'United States']' value must be an integer."]: (address.locality:pk=1) field_value was '['IL', 'United States']'" error.

Comment: @Dave I provided the sample code previously, now I have updated it for locality fixtures specifically and it is working now.

Comment: Added what you have but getting an "django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/maps/fixtures/seed_data.yaml': ["'['IL', 'United States']' value must be an integer."]: (address.locality:pk=1) field_value was '['IL', 'United States']'" error when running my script.

Comment: @Dave Sorry, there was minor typo in answer. `Country.objects.get_or_create(name=country)` should be `Country.objects.get_or_create(name=country)[0]`. Updated my answer

Comment: Ok so that would make the second line under "class CustomManager(models.Manager):" be "country = Country.objects.get_or_create(name=country)[0]"?  This results in the same error as before.  Further up in teh stack trace there's this -- "TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'".  Are we sure the YAML is structured properly?

Comment: @Dave Yes, I am sure that yaml file and above code is correct and running fine. I just copied paste above code and ran in my system. Can you please give me full stack trace and show your related code.

Comment: Included stack trace as an edit to my question.  If you would like to see the code, it is here -- https://github.com/chicommons/maps .  You would generate the error by running, "python web/manage.py loaddata web/maps/fixtures/seed_data.yaml" in a virtual environment.

Comment: Error is coming because you have added custom code in monkey_patching.py file and Django does not execute this file by default. Django looks for only models.py by default. So either move this code to models.py OR just add `from monkey_patching import *` into `models.py` file

Comment: Ok, I moved everything into "models.py" just to get this moving.  Now this line, "State.add_to_class('_default_manager', CustomManager())" causes the error, "AttributeError: can't set attribute".  I also updated the GitHub repo if that's useful.

Comment: please add requirements.txt file with all requirements. I am facing issues with installing all required dependencies.

Comment: @Dave It seems like, from Django 1.10, _default_manager is read-only. So you can use django1.8 for now. I am looking for other solutions too.

Comment: @Dave As shown here https://pypi.org/project/django-address/ django-address module is compatible by only Django1.7 and Django1.8. Why you are using it with django2.0?

Comment: I'm not tied to using the django-address module -- if there is another module that allows me to make a field in my model an address, I'm open to using that.

Comment: @dave you can check, address field code in django-address module and copy the code or you can add a separate question for it.

Comment: FWIW, django-address is compatible with the latest version of Django (you'll see commits to that effect in the Github repo) - the just forgot to update the compatibility specifiers for PyPi.

Comment: @Dave I have updated my solution and it is working fine for `Django==2.0`

Comment: Just got back from an out of town trip but this looks real good.  Thanks for all your persistence and help!

Answer (score 1):

I would offer an alternative approach, which is just to write your own [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) to import this data, instead of trying to make `loaddata` work - I think this is potentially much less effort.

This command works for the sample data you've provided - it may need some minor adjustments if you have more than just `address.locality` objects in your YAML file:

```
import yaml

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

from address.models import Country, State, Locality


class Command(BaseCommand):

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('file', nargs=1, type=str)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        f = options['file'][0]
        with open(f, 'r') as yamlfile:
            data = yaml.load(yamlfile)

        for row in data:
            if row['model'] == 'address.locality':
                state_name = row['fields']['state']['name']
                country_name = row['fields']['state']['country'][0]

                country_obj, _ = Country.objects.get_or_create(name=country_name)
                state_obj, _ = State.objects.get_or_create(country=country_obj, name=state_name)

                Locality.objects.get_or_create(
                    pk=row['pk'], 
                    state=state_obj, 
                    postal_code=row['fields']['postal_code'], 
                    name=row['fields']['name']
                )
```

(Side note - the format of your YAML is a little weird, as it provides a list for `country`. I would have thought a state can only belong to a single country?).

Answer (score 0):

In the source code of this package, `Locality.state` field is related to `State` model by a `foreignKey`. So, your data fixture `state` field must be an integer of the related table name.

See [django-address source code](https://github.com/furious-luke/django-address/blob/master/address/models.py#L211)

PS: In your case you must build all the related models that `Locality` model is related to. If not you'll have a data integrity error ... And all bunch of other errors.

Comment: Per my comment to your other comment, I would like to build these models on the fly and as such, have defined "get_by_natural_key" in my apps/monkey_patching.py file.  I would like to figure out why that part isn't working.